# Launching photo screen a second time on iOS8 when Calabash iOS is linked

Tags: ios8, calabash-ios

Problem with launching photo screen a second time on iOS8 when Calabash-ios is linked.

When the user takes a photo in our app, she can save it, but can decide to go back and give it another go at a later time. When the app is built for iOS 8, we see the following behaviour:

Taking the first photo works OK, retaking it without leaving the photo screen works fine, as well.

But when a photo is saved and the photo screen is launched a second time, the photo preview area - the viewfinder - on the screen is just black and unable to take a photo. When I switch between the two cameras on the phone, the previously saved photograph is flipped as a transition animation. Exiting the photo screen and launching it again gives the same.
This happens even when launching the app manually.
It's only happening on iOS 8, tested with iOS 7 and it works fine.

```
$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 6.0.1
Build version 6A317

$ calabash-ios version
0.10.1

$ calabash.framework/Resources/version
0.10.1
```

I have a sample app to reproduce the issue that only takes photos. It works as expected when built without Calabash, but has the same issue when Calabash is linked.

XCode logs show the Calabash server is launched:

```
cameratest-cal[629:270640] Creating the server: <LPHTTPServer: 0x17d6b7f0>
cameratest-cal[629:270640] Calabash iOS server version: CALABASH VERSION: 0.10.1
cameratest-cal[629:270640] simroot: (null)
cameratest-cal[629:270640] Started LPHTTP server on port 37265
cameratest-cal[629:270713] Bonjour Service Published: domain(local.) type(_http._tcp.) name(Calabash Server)
cameratest-cal[629:270640] Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
cameratest-cal[629:270640] Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
```

Any idea what might cause this behaviour?

Comment: > I have a sample app to reproduce the issue that only takes photos.  Can you share this sample app?  I would like to reproduce locally.  I am the calabash-ios gem and server maintainer.

Comment: Hello @jmoody,
I no longer have access to the code, but have sent a mail to my ex-colleagues to contact you. Thanks!